# bulkTransfer returns positive value but communication is not successful

Tags: java, android, usb, cdc

### As stated by *Google* at [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#bulkTransfer(android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int))

> public int bulkTransfer (UsbEndpoint endpoint, byte[] buffer, int
> length, int timeout)
>
> **Returns** length of data transferred (or zero) for **success**, or negative value for failure

---

### Well, after performing a bulkTransfer in my app for a USB CDC communication

```
// send data to usb device
byte[] bytes = data.getBytes();
sentBytes = connection.bulkTransfer(output, bytes, bytes.length, 1000);
```

`sentBytes` is receiving the value of `16`, which is great, because I'm sending 16 bytes indeed.

It *should* indicate that the bytes were sent correctly. :-)

However, they're **NOT**. I can't see any results on the other side.

---

### After doing a rearch I found out that it could be an Interface problem, so here it's how I'm getting it from the device:

```
private void setupConnection()
    {
        // find the right interface
        for(int i = 0; i < usbDevice.getInterfaceCount(); i++)
        {
            // communications device class (CDC) type device
            if(usbDevice.getInterface(i).getInterfaceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CDC_DATA)
            {
                intf = usbDevice.getInterface(i);

                // find the endpoints
                for(int j = 0; j < intf.getEndpointCount(); j++)
                {
                    if(intf.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT && intf.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK)
                    {
                        // from android to device
                        output = intf.getEndpoint(j);
                    }

                    if(intf.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN && intf.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK)
                    {
                        // from device to android
                        input = intf.getEndpoint(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### What could I be possibly missing?

Comment: Have you invoked claimInterface() before bulkTransfer?

Comment: yes, it is invoked right after setupConnection is called.

Comment: Same situation at my side. Getting correct transferred bytes length but not printing all data at USB Printer. Working fine in some android devices and not in some others. Is you have any more idea or if it's solved then can you please help me?